# regression with multiple response variable in R

Tags: r

How can I express multiple response variables for linear model?

For example, I can do this with single response variable

```
 lm(Y1 ~ X1+X2+X3, data=somedata)
```

But if I want to use Y1-Y100 response variable in the model, how can I do that?

UPDATE: I am hasty. I just found an answer from http://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@r-project.org/msg73770.html

```
with(data, lm.fit(x=cbind(Intercept=1,x1,x2,x3), y=cbind(y1,y2,y3)))
```

and this one works too

```
 lm(cbind(Y1,Y2,Y3) ~ X1+X2+X3, data=somedata)
```

Comment: How about [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26585/how-to-do-a-generalized-linear-model-with-multiple-dependent-variables-in-r)?

Comment: @ConjugatePrior Oh my ignorance :) That is working OK too. Thanks!